# How to deploy the Shoes 3.3.7 application in Windows 64bit and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby, windows, shoes

I have a ready application Shoes 3.3.7, which I wrote in the Ubuntu 18.04 system.

This application consists of the rb file and two folders, one contains the images used when the application is switched on, the second contains graphs of simulations carried out in the application.

I want to create an executable file / installer / anything that will allow me to use the application in Windows 64bit and Ubuntu, without any shoes, ruby, etc., it has to be a truly ready application. I mean, the person who will install it is not to worry about ruby and shoes

Is there a right way to do it? Should I rewrite the application for something else that will enable it? For what?

I tried to pack the application in GUI Shoes without success. The resulting files did not work on the same computer on which the application was created or on fresh Windows.

The app works correctly in Ubuntu, in Shoes, the charts are saved and displayed. In contrast, in Windows, only the application starts working, and the creation and display of subsequent charts do not.

https://github.com/KamilSuchanek95/small_lotka_volterra_shoesapp

This is my application. The rb file and folders: image_charts, image_start, are part of the project. The MyLotka-Volterra folder is just a rough draft.
The application requires a gem numo-gnuplot.

The application is used to visualize the Lotka-Volterra model. To work properly, press the three buttons from left to right to load the parameters, solve the model and draw. The initial parameters correspond to the initial graphs.

Comment: You want a ruby application to run without a ruby interpreter? You know that if you bundle this application the first thing that will have to be copied into that bundle is ruby and all the dependencies. You could look at [ocra](https://github.com/larsch/ocra) for windows deployment never tried it with shoes but has worked for fxruby in the past. But there is no way you can write an application in ruby/shoes and not include ruby and shoes as part of the deployment You are essentially asking for a peanut butter and jelly sandwich without peanut butter and jelly

Comment: It's supposed to contain ruby ​​and shoes, but the person who will install it does not bother about it, that's what I meant. I apologize for misleading.